# Opening kivy widgets without the terminal?

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, kivy

I'm new to programming and learning to use python with kivy. I have windows 7. Is it possible to open kivy widgets without the terminal automatically opening in the background?

Answer (score 1):

use `pythonw.exe` that is in the python installation directories.

if you have virtualenv installed and your kivy project rests in a virtualenv,

try

`/<virtual_env_foler>/scripts/pythonw.exe` for `pythonw.exe`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by using pythonw.exe? I changed the file ending to .pyw and the terminal window still opened.